# Array data format redis pub sub channel

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, nosql, redis

I am trying to publish a normal javascript array on a redis channel through node eg- [1,2,3]. Which i am then capturing through predis by subscribing to the same channel.

However the data always shows up as [object Object]. I have tried json stringify but parsing or on print_r the variable still shows up as [object Object] in php.

Anything that i am overlooking?

Comment: You have overlooked adding code samples in your question such that people might be bale to help you better.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the issue. There was a problem with the json structure.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you are not using `toString()` method anywhere to convert your array into a string. `[object Object]` is exactly what you'd expect if you use `toString()` instead of `JSON.stringify()`